# Asp.NET WebGrid with Bootstrap pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4

There is default Bootstrap pagiantion

```html
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

In Asp.NET WebGrid I only can

```
footerStyle: "pagination",
```

In HTML of WebGrid I see this

```
<tfoot>
    <tr  class="pagination">
        <td colspan="8">1 <a href="/Communities/ICareFor?page=2">2</a> <a href="/Communities/ICareFor?page=2">&gt;</a> </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

What a easiest way to take in WebGrid bootstrap pagination style?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://github.com/mdobie/WebGridPagerReplacement  - this work good for WebGrid. Thank's to author.